# Unable to reflect the selected values from dropdown inside a heading or a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I am choosing a value from the dropdown so that it at least can get reflected in the heading, it is showing, devices.map is not a function. devices is an array where the data from the API got fetched. Below is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const Devdropdown = () => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState([]);
  const url = "..";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getDevices() {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const body = await response.json();
      setDevices(body.data);
    }
    getDevices();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDevices(e.target.value);
  };

  const uniqueDeviceIds = useMemo(
    () => Array.from(new Set(devices.map((device) => device.device_id))),
    [devices]
  );

  console.log(uniqueDeviceIds);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Aircraft {}</h1>
      <select
        value={uniqueDeviceIds}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="select an option"
      >
        {devices
          ? uniqueDeviceIds.map((deviceId) => (
              <option key={deviceId}>{deviceId}</option>
            ))
          : null}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Devdropdown;
```

So, in the Aircraft {} line, what should go inside the curly braces? uniqueDeviceIds or devices?
And when I am having the onChange inside select, whenever I am going to select the element, it is showing, device.map is not a function.

Comment: If `devices.map` is not a function then `devices` is not an array.  When you debug, when the error occurs, what is the value of `devices`?  What was the expected value?  Why?  If I were to *guess*, this is very likely changing the value of `devices` to something that is not an array: `setDevices(e.target.value)`

Comment: Ok. I have changed devices to array. 
const body = await response.json();
      setDevices([body.data]);

Now in uniqueDeviceIds, it is showing undefined. How to overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the map function must be performed on an array variable. However, in `handleChange` you are setting your state to string.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setDevices(e.target.value); <---
};
```

What you would have to do is create a new state that will hold the currently selected item.

Comment: Ok . Can you give me an example related to this? Suppose, if I'd take 
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

Then what will be the default value for the selected ? In handleChange function, how to execute that so that the value changes and sets it to the new value?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-neco-vropq8?file=/src/App.js